# How to change opacity of image programmatically and save it in Gallery

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have two images on top of each other, by changing the opacity of the top image at run time and then combine that two images(means make that two images as one image) and save it in Gallery. In android studio how to achieve this?.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are full screen, simply make your own screenshot. There are plenty of great libraries that will do this for you if you want or you can use simple code that I put in a class I named ImageHelper like this:

```
public static Bitmap takeScreenshotOfView(Activity context, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat){
        Bitmap screenshot = null;

    try {
    // create bitmap screen capture
    View v1 = context.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    File imageFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "A35_temp" + File.separator + "screenshot_temp");

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    int quality = 100;

    screenshot.compress(compressFormat, quality, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

} catch (Throwable e) {
    // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return screenshot;
}
```

And just use it like:

```
Bitmap screenshot = ImageHelper.takeScreenshotOfView(this, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG);
```

Now if you need just capture the ImageView area you can either get it by view or get the parent of both image views so that they are included. You can also specify full screen but start at imageView start points and end points. Here is some sample code I wrote for managing screenshots of individual areas.

```
 private void convertCardToBitmap(boolean sendOnComplete){
    if(!mIsForStore) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.downloading_to_gallery), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    CardView cardView = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view_id);

    cardView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    cardView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    //cardView.measure((int)height, (int)width);
    cardView.layout(0, 0, cardView.getMeasuredWidth(), cardView.getMeasuredHeight());
    //cardView.layout(0, 0, (int)width, (int)height);
    cardView.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cardView.getDrawingCache());

    saveBitmapToGallery(bitmap, sendOnComplete);

}
private void saveBitmapToGallery(Bitmap cardToSave, boolean sendFileWhenSaved){
    OutputStream output;
    // Find the SD Card path
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Create a new folder in SD Card
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAppPathDir/");
    dir.mkdirs();

    String imageName = mSelectedPerson.getFirstName() + "_" + mSelectedPerson.getLastName() + "_" + FileNameHelper.getNowTimeStamp();

    // Create a name for the saved image
    File file = new File(dir, imageName + ".jpg");

    try {
        int count = 1;
        //if file exists add 1 on the end and loop until finding a name that doesn't exist.
        while(file.exists()){
            file = new File(dir, imageName + count + ".jpg");
            count++;

        }

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        cardToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        addImageToGallery(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if(sendFileWhenSaved){
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_FILE_TO_SHARE, file.getAbsolutePath());
            intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_SELECTED_IMAGE, mSelectedCardModel);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

        } else if (mIsForStore) {
            uploadImageToS3(file.getAbsolutePath());

        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.saved_to_gallery), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_failed_save_to_gallery) + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
private void uploadImageToS3(String filePath){
    final File newImageFile = new File(filePath);
    showProgressDialog(TAG, getString(R.string.loading_please_wait));

    //For auth route
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(CognitoManager.getS3ClientID(), CognitoManager.getS3ClientSecret());

    AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, this);
    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(CognitoManager.getS3BucketName(), newImageFile.getName(), newImageFile);
    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if(state.compareTo(TransferState.COMPLETED) == 0){
                String imgURLOfUploadComplete = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/" + CognitoManager.getS3BucketName() + "/" + newImageFile.getName();
                hideProgressDialog(TAG);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_IMAGE_URL, imgURLOfUploadComplete);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                if(newImageFile.exists()){
                    newImageFile.delete();

                }
                finish();

            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            if(bytesTotal != 0) {
                //For viewing progress
                int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            A35Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.error_uploading_s3_part1) + id + getString(R.string.error_uploading_s3_part2) + ex.getMessage());
            hideProgressDialog(TAG);
            showDialogMessage(getString(error), getString(R.string.error_failed_create_image_alert_id) + error);

        }

    });

}
public void addImageToGallery(final String filePath) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Hope that helps :).
I will warn you though when you start setDrawCacheEnabled it can have strange behaviors on the screen and cause you to need to redraw as it seems to sometimes remove constraints. For this reason, I often just open a new blank screen with the content that I am converting into image, finish the work then close.

So just see how it works for you and decide where to go from there. Most libraries I tried also had the same problem, that is why I just wrote my own.